# When I click text box how to clear Successful message in javascript

Tags: javascript

When I submit data with the submit button I got "Successfully Inserted" message I need to clear this message when i click text box how can i clear this message.

Thank you

Comment: Please, post what you've done so far. We need to see code so we're able to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try This**

```
<input id="textbox1" type="text"  onmouseenter="clearSuccessLabel()" >
<input id="textbox2" type="text"  onmouseenter="clearSuccessLabel()" >
<input id="textbox3" type="text"  onmouseenter="clearSuccessLabel()" >
<input id="textbox4" type="text"  onmouseenter="clearSuccessLabel()" >
<input id="textbox5" type="text"  onmouseenter="clearSuccessLabel()" >
<span id="alert">Success!</span>

function clearSuccessLabel() 
{
  document.getElementById('alert').innerHTML = "";
}
```

Comment: Your solution does not clear the message _on click_, that's what he asked for. Also, it's safer to bind events to elements instead of declaring it on the tags.

Answer (score 1):

To properly help you, you should post some actual code you've written.

With what you have given, i can assume you could do the following:

```js
window.onload = function() {
    var elArr = document.querySelectorAll('input[type=text]');

    for (var i = 0, len = elArr.length; i < len; i++) {
        elArr[i].addEventListener('focus', clearText);
    }
}

function clearText() {
  document.getElementById('alert').style.display = 'none';
}
```

```css
span {
  color: red;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<input id="textbox" type="text">
<input id="textbox2" type="text">
<input id="textbox3" type="text">
<input id="textbox4" type="text">
<input id="textbox5" type="text">
<span id="alert">Success!</span>
```

Comment: Hi, @doutriforce, Thank you for helping but your code for single text box but I have five text boxes in this case how can i take